# Collapse cases in a dataframe only under certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to collapse the dataset below across the Id_no, but only when other variables meet certain conditions, and calculating a special collapse variable.

```
df <- structure(list(Id_no = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("n1", 
"n2", "n3"), class = "factor"), Band = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Band 1", "Band 2", "Band 3"), class = "factor"), 
    median = c(252, 191, 107, 130.5, 61.5, 217), sample_size = c(19L, 
    20L, 1L, 20L, 12L, 1544L)), .Names = c("Id_no", "Band", "median", 
"sample_size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
  Id_no   Band median sample_size
1    n1 Band 1  252.0          19
2    n1 Band 2  191.0          20
3    n1 Band 3  107.0           1
4    n2 Band 1  130.5          20
5    n2 Band 2   61.5          12
6    n3 Band 1  217.0        1544
```

The collapse variable would be the ratio of a median in Band 1 vs mean median between Bands 2 and 3.

This would be calculated for Id_no that actually have entries for both B1 and at least one of B2 or B3.

In addition, the B2 and B3 medians should be considered only if sample size is >=10.

The resulting table I'm looking for is this:

```
  Id_no b1_vs_rest
1    n1       1.32
2    n2       2.12
```

The first step is probably to remove cases where sample size doesn't meet the minimum:

```
df <- subset(df, sample_size >=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(Id_no) %>% 
              filter(sample_size >= 10) %>%
              summarise(b1_vs_rest=median[Band == "Band 1"]/mean(median[Band != "Band 1"])) %>%
              filter(!is.nan(b1_vs_rest))
```

Notes:

1. With `dplyr`, first `filter` to keep only those rows with `sample_size` greater than or equal to `10`.
2. Then `group_by` `Id_no` and `summarise` to compute the ratio for each `Id_no` selecting for the numerator the `median` for `Band == "Band 1"` and for the denominator the medians for all other Bands.
3. If neither `"Band 1"` nor `"Band 2"` exists, then `mean` will return `NaN` and the result will also be `NaN`. So, we `filter` again to keep only non-`NaN` values.

The result using your data is as expected:

```
print(res)
### A tibble: 2 x 2
##   Id_no b1_vs_rest
##  <fctr>      <dbl>
##1     n1   1.319372
##2     n2   2.121951
```

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood the question slightly. b1_vs_rest should be the median in B1 over mean median beween B2 & B3. The figures are identical with ulfelder solution, because in Id_no = n1, sample_size in B3 is <10 so is removed, and so b1_vs_rest = B1/B2; but if sample_size was >10, the numbers would be different.

Comment: I tried modifying this part to: `b1_vs_rest=f(median[Band=="Band 1"])/mean(c(f(median[Band=="Band 2"]),f(median[Band=="Band 3"])))` but now the values are 2x what they should be. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mihael: I see, you are correct. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works now on the toy dataset, but when I try it with the real data it gives the same error as another solution: `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :   object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` What could be the reason? The "real" dataset is a result of a call `summaryBy` from package `doBy` and is of a class `data.frame`

Comment: @Mihael: Hmm, see my simplified solution. It will probably still give you that error, though. If you could, please post the result of `str` for your real dataset.

Comment: It works on the original dataset now, thanks. Not sure what I did though... The results match with another solution given by @akrun (but without `with = FALSE`),

Comment: @Mihael: One more thing. The above solution does **assume** that "Band 1" will always have more than 10 samples. If that is not the case, then you need to pass `median[Band=="Band 1"]` through something like my previous function `f` where it detects `length` of this subset wrt `0` and set to `NaN` if it is. That is: `f <- function(m) {if (length(m)==0) NaN else m}`. An alternative is to just use `mean(median[Band=="Band 1"])` in the numerator,  which will return the singleton `median` if exist and `NaN` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and an `if...else` construct to vary the output by your condition. Per your question (and not your expected results), I'm assuming that you want the ratio of the median for Band 1 to the mean of the medians for Bands 2 and 3 in cases where you have all three.

```
d2 <- df %>%
  filter(sample_size >= 10) %>%
  group_by(Id_no) %>%
  summarise(b1_vs_rest = if(any(Band == "Band 2") & any(Band == "Band 3")) {
                           median[Band == "Band 1"] / (mean(c(median[Band == "Band 2"], median[Band == "Band 3"])))
                         } else if(any(Band == "Band 2")) {
                           median[Band == "Band 1"] / median[Band == "Band 2"]
                         } else if(any(Band == "Band 3")) {
                           median[Band == "Band 1"] / median[Band == "Band 3"]
                         } else {
                           NA
                         }) %>%
  filter(!is.na(b1_vs_rest))
```

Result:

```
> d2
# A tibble: 2 × 2
   Id_no b1_vs_rest
  <fctr>      <dbl>
1     n1   1.319372
2     n2   2.121951
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works fine on this example, but when I try it with the real data, it gives me the following error: Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :   object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.... Do you have any ideas? Obviously I substituted the corresponding variable names.

Comment: Hard to say without your actual data to test against. Probably an issue with differences in data frame or column names. If you start with just the first pipe and add one pipe stepwise, at what point does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), reshape from 'long' to 'wide' (`dcast`), remove the NA rows (`na.omit`), specify the `.SDcols` as the 'Band' columns, divide the first column (`.SD[[1]]`) by the sum of the other columns (`` Reduce(`+`, ...) ``) to get the expected output.

```
library(data.table)#1.9.7+
na.omit(dcast(setDT(df)[sample_size >= 10], Id_no~Band, value.var = "median"))[,
  .(Id_no, b1_vs_rest = .SD[[1]]/Reduce(`+`, .SD[, -1, with = FALSE])) , .SDcols = -1]
#   Id_no b1_vs_rest
#1:    n1   1.319372
#2:    n2   2.121951
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but the newest devel version doesn't require `with = FALSE` anymore

Comment: Indeed, using the original answer with `with = FALSE` was giving wrong results on the real dataset, but removing this produced correct results, matching those of aichao's solution

Comment: @Mihael I was using the devel version.  I don't know if that makes any difference

Comment: @akrun I was using the devel version too. The CRAN versin didn't even work at all.

Comment: @Mihael I am not sure about the problem in your end.  With the example you showed, I didn't find any problem